# Replication dynamic panel estimation of a within and a system-GMM R plm/pgmm versus Stata xtabond2

Tags: dynamic, stata, panel-data, plm

Anderson & Ponnusamy (2022; DOI: 10.1111/agec.12745) are estimating some dynamic panel data models. They also provide replication data and code.

I was trying to replicate results of a two-way within and a two-way one-step system GMM estimation (Table 5, Panel A and Panel B) with R:

```
R.01 Panel A: plm(agri_emp ~ 1+ lag(agri_emp,1) + loggni + loggni_sq, 
               data =(data_est2), effect = "twoways", model = "within", index = c("country","year"))
```

and

```
R.02 Panel B: pgmm(agri_emp ~ 1+ lag(agri_emp,1) + loggni + loggni_sq | lag(agri_emp,2:22) + lag(loggni,1:99), 
               data =data_est2, effect = "twoways", model = "onestep", index = c("country","year"),
               transformation = "ld")
```

versus Stata (v15) (adapted from author's code)

```
Stata.01 Panel A: xtreg agri_emp loggni loggni_sq l.agri_emp i.year, fe robust
```

and

```
Stata.02 Panel B: xtabond2 agri_emp loggni loggni_sq l.agri_emp i.year, gmmstyle(agri_emp, laglimits(2 22)) gmmstyle(loggni, laglimits(1 .)) ivstyle(i.year, p) noleveleq robust nodiffsargan
```

First, the within estimation replicated the results of the article, in R and Stata. Only standard errors of the R estimation were too small, but that is not so much important for my question.

The problem is with the system GMM. In Stata, the results were perfectly replicated. In R, the code from above (R02 Panel B), after quite some time it produced an error:

> Error in solve.default(crossprod(WX, t.CP.WX.A1)):
> lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[5,5] = 0

Did I make an error specifying the pgmm arguments? Does anyone had a similar problem estimating dynamic panel data system GMM in R? Does anyone know a blog or book or article which contrasted R and Stata functionality regarding dynamic panel data model estimation?